# Why Google OAuth Client appears in development

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I am trying to get **Google OAuth screen consent verification** for my project, but it is not approved. The reason is that development clients cannot be approved. I am sharing the message from Google below.

However, when I check the details of the client, there are only url that I use in the live (there is no localhost url). Even though I created a separate project for development and created a client under it called staging, I still get the following warning.

I did not fully understand what else to do. Can you help me please?

**Google Message**

[image]

**Related Client**

[image]

Comment: If you remove the development endpoint then you will need to submit it for verification again.    Do you have a client side and server side application?  I am wondering why you are setting both javascript origin and redirect uri.    Is the redirect URI on one of the domains that you verified in search console?

Comment: @DaImTo There is no development endpoint in the client. Yes I have client & server side 2 projects. But I generate a auth url in nodejs and open it in react project. If Oauth is successful, I close the react project in the browser and open the react project in a new tab in the redirect section in node js.

Comment: Do you have more then one client in that project?  and you did click the publish button corect?

Comment: @DaImTo No, I have only one client. Which publish button? Just last week I applied for the verification process.

Comment: There's nothing obvious that you've shown about why this would be rejected. You should push back to the verification team and ask for clarification about why it has been rejected.

Comment: @Prisoner Thanks for your answer. In our guess, they thought the .dev domain name was development mode. I will contact again stating this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of an update on this. (Took a while to find the right team at google to contact)

This was an issue with the reviewer guidelines which has since been updated.

Apparently **.dev** often is used for testing - but it's also used for production as in this case.

People using **.dev** domains should no longer have issues with verifying applications.

Comment: Jan 2023, was flagged as Development/staging for .dev domain. Replying to the email that it was indeed the production domain resolved it.

Comment: their guidelines should have been adjusted.   I wonder if they put it back.