# Verification issue with GCP Project. Google says the project is still in "development or staging app" but its not

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-fit-api

I'm building a mobile app which uses Firebase products and Google Sign in. I don't have GCP project except the Firebase. And I want to use Google Fitness API but permission screen says "App is not verified by Google". I'm trying to [verify the application by Google](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en).

Problem is, Google is keep sending an email that my cloud project looks like a development project. They've sent that maybe 5 times now. I've been emailing with them more than a month now. I send them demo video of how we use scopes, I've filled missing information about the app. And I did all the steps above from [OAuth Consent Screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) section of Google Cloud Console.

> Hi, Thanks for your patience while we reviewed your project.
>
> It looks like your project *project name (id: *projectId) is a development or
> staging app. Development/staging projects, or projects which are not
> yet live to the public, are not eligible for verification. Please
> respond to this email to let us know if your app is still in
> development.

**Question is, what causes your GCP project to look like a development/staging app?**

[image]

Comment: Would the person who closed voted this as "needs clarity" please comment on what is not clear about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing localhost from authorized domains on firebase.

Since every Firebase project is Google Cloud Project, having localhost as Authorized Domain on my Firebase account was causing this error.

Steps are simple:

Authentication -> Sign in method -> Delete localhost from authorized domains.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Application verification can be very tricky.   They are normally very good about responding if you ask for more information.

This may seam obvious at first but check that you are looking at the correct project they are mentioning.  The image you show is of a project that is set to production but is it in fact  *project name (id: *projectId).

Second check any redirect URIs you have added, they cant be localhost, or HTTP.

If one of your redirect uris is a **.dev domain**.  Email them back and remind them that a **.dev** is your production domain and is not a development domain.  This issue should  [have been fixed in their guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67105384/why-google-oauth-client-appears-in-development),  but lets double check this one anyway.

Third check the everything under App domain. Home page link, Privacy policy then check all the Authorized domains. Nothing can be localhost, they must all be HTTPS.

If that doesn't work email them back and tell them it is in production and send them an image and ask for more information

Comment: Thank you so much, I've removed localhost from Authorized Domains on Firebase. I'll keep the post updated.

Comment: Remember this has nothing to do with firebase this is your project on [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)